# Closing python requests connection

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
requests.get(path_url, timeout=100)
```

In the above usage of python requests library, does the connection close automatically once requests.get is done running? If not, how can I make for certain that connection is closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a call to a `session.close` behind the `get` code. If using a proper IDE like PyCharm for example, you can follow the `get` code to see what is happening. Inside `get` there is a call to request:

```
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
```

Within the definition of that `request` method, the call to `session.close` is made.

By following the link [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L57) to the requests repo, there is a call being made for the session control:

```
# By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
# avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
# cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
with sessions.Session() as session:
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks @idjaw, does your answer also hold if I call requests.get()?

Comment: Yes. As specified in the answer, the `get` call makes a call to `request('get'...` as specified in the line starting the the `return` in my answer. If you follow the link I provided, you will actually also see the `get` method there and how it makes the call to `request`.